# PostgreSQL Full Text Search with Hibernate Query Language cannot execute query

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, spring-boot, hql

I am developing a full text search service. I use PostgreSQL's built-in FTS query [syntax](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/textsearch-intro.html#TEXTSEARCH-MATCHING). As you know, I need to use `@@` characters to use it. But, this characters are not recognized by HQL, you cannot directly write it like inside the sql. One option is to use `nativeQuery`, which I used to use. But, due to software's requirements, now I need to use HQL. For this purpose, I tried to implement [this](https://www.zymr.com/postgresql-full-text-searchfts-hibernate/) implementation.

In that implementation first you create a `PostgreSQLFTSFunction` class. For me it is:

```java
public class BFTSFunction implements SQLFunction {
    @Override
    public boolean hasArguments() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasParenthesesIfNoArguments() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public Type getReturnType(Type type, Mapping mapping) throws QueryException {
        return new BooleanType();
    }

    @Override
    public String render(Type type, List list, SessionFactoryImplementor sessionFactoryImplementor)
            throws QueryException {

        if (list.size() != 2) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("The function must be passed 3 args");
        }
        String field = (String) list.get(0);
        String value = (String) list.get(1);

        String fragment = null;
        fragment =  "( to_tsvector(coalesce(" + field + ",' ')) @@ " + "plainto_tsquery('%" +
                value + "%')) ";

        return fragment;

    }
}
```

Then need to create `CustomPostgreSQLDialect`:(I have, for sure, added dialect configuration onto application.yml file)

```java
public class FTSPostgresDialect extends PostgisDialect {
    public FTSPostgresDialect() {
        super();
        registerFunction("fts", new BFTSFunction());
    }
}
```

Lastly I created HQL in my RepositoryImp

```java
Query<Long> q = session.createQuery(
                "select b.id from B b where (fts(b.name,:searched) = true )",Long.class).setParameter("searched",searched);

List<Long> listResults = q.getResultList();
```

But the query created by hibernate cannot be executed. Full error will be given below, but I should say that, logged query in the console (created by Hibernate) can be executed in `pgAdmin`. Therefore, Query creation process is correct. Then, where can be the error is?

Full error is given:

```
rg.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute query; SQL [select b0_.id as col_0_0_ from bs b0_ where ( b0_.deleted=false) and ( to_tsvector(coalesce(b0_.name,' ')) @@ plainto_tsquery('%?%')) =true]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.DataException: could not execute query
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:261) ~[spring-orm-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:223) ~[spring-orm-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
...
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.DataException: could not execute query
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:118) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:111) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
...
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The column index is out of range: 1, number of columns: 0.
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.SimpleParameterList.bind(SimpleParameterList.java:65) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar:42.2.5]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.SimpleParameterList.setStringParameter(SimpleParameterList.java:128) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar:42.2.5]


2019-07-16 10:08:59.328 ERROR 8248 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute query; SQL [select b0_.id as col_0_0_ from bs b0_ where ( b0_.deleted=false) and ( to_tsvector(coalesce(b0_.name,' ')) @@ plainto_tsquery('%?%')) =true]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.DataException: could not execute query] with root cause

org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The column index is out of range: 1, number of columns: 0.
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.SimpleParameterList.bind(SimpleParameterList.java:65) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar:42.2.5]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.SimpleParameterList.setStringParameter(SimpleParameterList.java:128) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar:42.2.5]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.bindString(PgPreparedStatement.java:996) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar:42.2.5]
```

If additional info is needed, I will fastly send it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interestingly, as the error suggests, hibernate cannot bind the parameters onto sql. I couldn't make it happen. But in my situation, I could just concatenate as string, therefore problem is resolved by changing HQL from:

```java
Query<Long> q = session.createQuery(
                "select b.id from B b where (fts(b.name,:searched) = true )",Long.class)
                .setParameter("searched",searched);
```

to:

```java
Query<Long> q = session.createQuery(
                "select b.id from B b where (fts(b.name,"+searched+") = true )",Long.class);
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is unnecessary quotes in a plainto_tsquery call:

```
    fragment =  "( to_tsvector(coalesce(" + field + ",' ')) @@ " + "plainto_tsquery('%" +
            value + "%')) ";
```

It should be:

```
    fragment =  "( to_tsvector(coalesce(" + field + ",' ')) @@ " + "plainto_tsquery(" +
            value + ")) ";
```

I removed those `%` too, because it won't work like that. `value` won't have an actual parameter value, it would have `?` in it to create a query, that will be reused for actual executions. If you want to wrap the given value into `%`, you'll have to do it with SQL, not Java code.